# Value of type 'CustomButton' has no member 'touchDown'

Tags: uibutton, swift3, xcode8

I have created custom button class and override all touches methods. It works fine in `swift 2` and `Xcode 7.3.1`. But when I open same app in `Xcode 8.0`, it will show errors :

> Value of type 'CustomButton' has no member 'touchDown'
>
> Value of type 'CustomButton' has no member 'touchUpInside'
>
> Value of type 'CustomButton' has no member 'touchDragExit'
>
> Value of type 'CustomButton' has no member 'touchDragEnter'
>
> Value of type 'CustomButton' has no member 'touchCancel'

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable
@objc public class CustomButton: UIButton {

    private func addTargets() {
    
        //------ add target -------

         self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchDown(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
         self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchUpInside(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
         self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchDragExit(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.TouchDragExit)
         self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchDragEnter(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.TouchDragEnter)
         self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.touchCancel(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.TouchCancel)
    }

    func touchDown(sender: CustomButton) {
       self.layer.opacity = 0.4
    }

    func touchUpInside(sender: CustomButton) {
       self.layer.opacity = 1.0
    }

    func touchDragExit(sender: CustomButton) {
       self.layer.opacity = 1.0
    }

    func touchDragEnter(sender: CustomButton) {
       self.layer.opacity = 0.4
    }

    func touchCancel(sender: CustomButton) {
        self.layer.opacity = 1.0
    }
}
```

If anyone have any solution, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep your method headers as are in your code, you need to change the selector references to `#selector(touchDown(sender:))`, and so on.

(Generally, you have no need to prefix `self.`.)

Remember all functions and methods now have consistent label treatment for their first parameters. [SE-0046](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0046-first-label.md)

(You may find many good articles, searching with "swift3 selector".)

If you want to keep the selector references, you need to change the methods like:

```
func touchDown(_ sender: CustomButton) {
```

---

For addition, `#selector(touchDown)` would work, if your class has only one `touchDown(...)` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution as @OOPer suggested, but there also need to change `UIControlEvents` in small case. In `Xcode 7.3.1` it was `UIControlEvents.TouchDown` but now it has to be `UIControlEvents.touchDown`.

It will be like :

```
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDown(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDown)
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchUpInside(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDragExit(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDragExit)
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchDragEnter(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchDragEnter)
self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(touchCancel(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchCancel)
```