# How to use addTarget method in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, selector

here is my `button` object

```
    let loginRegisterButton:UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 50 , g: 80, b: 130)
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()
```

and here is my function

```
    func handleRegister(){

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password,completion: { (user, error) in

        if error != nil
        { print("Error Occured")}

        else
        {print("Successfully Authenticated")}
    })        
}
```

I'm getting compile error, if addTarget removed it compiles successfully

Comment: Try this `button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister()), for: .touchUpInside)`.

Comment: `handleRegister` action are in the same controller? Also you havn't set the frame of `UIButton`.

Comment: yes, I do have an another function for its constraints   func constraints() {loginRegisterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputview.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputview.bottomAnchor, constant: 12).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: inputview.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        loginRegisterButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true }

Comment: @Ninja13 Then problem is may be with your button constraints try to set just frame once and check it is working or not.

Comment: i changed code like this and it worked                                                            lazy var loginRegisterButton:UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor(r: 50 , g: 80, b: 130)
    button.setTitle("Register", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

Answer (score 116):

Yes, don't add "()" if there is no param

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister), for: .touchUpInside).
```

and if you want to get the sender

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(_:)), for: .touchUpInside). 

func handleRegister(sender: UIButton){
   //...
}
```

Edit:

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

no longer works, you need to replace `_` in the selector with a variable name you used in the function header, in this case it would be `sender`, so the working code becomes:

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: ok that is really easy.. but how add a value example..
`button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(str: "Hello")), for: .touchUpInside)`
 ?

Comment: You cannot set parameter in a selector . The action depends on the origin of the target. If you want get the string of the button, get it from the sender in handleRegister(sender: UIButton)
let string = sender. currentTitle

Comment: One of the workarounds is to set the parameter as the button's accessibility element. But not sure if this is accepted by App Store since I only tried for Enterprise apps.

Answer (score 28):

**Try this with Swift 4**

```
buttonSection.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionWithParam(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
@objc func actionWithParam(sender: UIButton){
    //...
}

buttonSection.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionWithoutParam), for: .touchUpInside)
@objc func actionWithoutParam(){
    //...
}
```

Comment: Not a huge issue, but is there still no way to do this without exposing to @objc?

Comment: As Apple Official Documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective_c_runtime_features_in_swift), you need to use @objc to call your Selector Method, no other "pure swift" way of using the selector.

Answer (score 15):

Try this

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister()), for: .touchUpInside).
```

Just add parenthesis with name of method.

Also you can refer link : [Value of type 'CustomButton' has no member 'touchDown'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39509556/value-of-type-custombutton-has-no-member-touchdown/39509985#39509985)

Comment: Actually, don't add any parantheses

Answer (score 8):

```
  let button: UIButton = UIButton()
    button.setImage(UIImage(named:"imagename"), for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(YourClassName.backAction(_sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    button.frame = CGRect.init(x: 5, y: 100, width: 45, height: 45)
    view.addSubview(button)

    @objc public func backAction(_sender: UIButton) {

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

Try with swift 3

```
cell.TaxToolTips.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.TaxToolTips.addTarget(self, action: #selector(InheritanceTaxViewController.displayToolTipDetails(_:)), for:.touchUpInside)


 @objc func displayToolTipDetails(_ sender : UIButton) {
        print(sender.tag)
        let tooltipString = TaxToolTipsArray[sender.tag]
        self.displayMyAlertMessage(userMessage: tooltipString, status: 202)    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In swift 3 use this -

```
object?.addTarget(objectWhichHasMethod, action: #selector(classWhichHasMethod.yourMethod), for: someUIControlEvents)
```

For example(from my code) -

```
self.datePicker?.addTarget(self, action:#selector(InfoTableViewCell.datePickerValueChanged), for: .valueChanged)
```

Just give a `:` after method name if you want the sender as parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Try this with Swift 3

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(ClassName.handleRegister(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The poster's second comment from September 21st is spot on.  For those who may be coming to this thread later with the same problem as the poster, here is a brief explanation.  The other answers are good to keep in mind, but do not address the common issue encountered by this code.

In Swift, declarations made with the `let` keyword are constants.  Of course if you were going to add items to an array, the array can't be declared as a constant, but a segmented control should be fine, right?!  Not if you reference the completed segmented control in its declaration.

Referencing the object (in this case a `UISegmentedControl`, but this also happens with `UIButton`) **in its declaration** when you say `.addTarget` and let the target be `self`, things crash.  Why?  Because `self` is in the midst of being defined.  But we do want to define behaviour as part of the object... Declare it **lazily** as a variable with `var`.  The `lazy` fools the compiler into thinking that `self` is well defined - it silences your compiler from caring at the time of declaration.  Lazily declared variables don't get set until they are first called.  So in this situation, `lazy` lets you use the notion of `self` without issue while you set up the object, and then when your object gets a `.touchUpInside` or `.valueChanged` or whatever your 3rd argument is in your `.addTarget()`, **THEN** it calls on the notion of `self`, which at that point is fully established and totally prepared to be a valid target.  So it lets you be lazy in declaring your variable.  In cases like these, I think they could give us a keyword like `necessary`, but it is generally seen as a lazy, sloppy practice and you don't want to use it all over your code, though it may have its place in this sort of situation.  What it

There is no `lazy let` in Swift (no `lazy` for constants).

Here is the [Apple documentation on lazy](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH14-ID257).

Here is the [Apple on variables and constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).  There is a little more in their Language Reference under [Declarations](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
let loginRegisterButton:UIButton = {
//...  }()
```

Try:

```
lazy var loginRegisterButton:UIButton = {
//...  }()
```

That should fix the compile error!!!

Answer (score 1):

the Demo from Apple document. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/using_objective-c_runtime_features_in_swift

```
import UIKit
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    let myButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: NSNib.Name?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nibNameOrNil, bundle: nibBundleOrNil)
        // without parameter style
        let action = #selector(MyViewController.tappedButton)
        // with parameter style
        // #selector(MyViewController.tappedButton(_:))
        myButton.addTarget(self, action: action, forControlEvents: .touchUpInside)
    }

    @objc func tappedButton(_ sender: UIButton?) {
        print("tapped button")
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
}
```