# Ios pull-to-refresh strategy for UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, swift, pull-to-refresh

I have a `UIPageViewController` that can contain between 0 and 3 `UITableViewController` items. On opening the screen my app performs a request to the backend, retrieving a response that may contain up to 3 separate lists of data (note that the lists cannot be retrieved individually). Each list is displayed in one of the `UITableViewController` items. Each of these is only created when there is data to show for that view.

The question is, how would I go about implementing pull-to-refresh given the following:

- There may be no `UITableView` to provide a `UIRefreshControl`
- Pulling would refresh all of the pager's children not only the `UITableView` currently being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you will need a Scrollview to use the UIRefreshControl, otherwise how would you be able to pull it down. So lets get to that later. Your second part is somewhat difficult to answer, because you define how you want to update it, without more information or code snaps it will not be easy to help you. But what I can say that you should make functions that update your other tableviews so when the refreshcontrol is "activated" these functions get called.

You can call the functions like this:

```
yourRefreshControl.addTarget(target: Any?, action: #Selector, for: UIControlEvents)
```

If you are not sure how the addTarget function works [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617873/how-to-use-addtarget-method-in-swift-3) is a question on StackOverflow that may help

So now to the second part. To add the UIRefreshControl to the UIPageViewController you need first set up a scrollView as a subview of the control viewer, you can do so in storyBoard, after creating it and setting up all constraints create an outlet to your UIPageViewController class and create a second variable called refreshControl or however you want to call it. so you will have these 2 variables:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var refreshControll: UIRefreshControl!
```

Then in the onViewDidLoad function, you just have to add the refreshControl to the ScrollView and magic happens :]. To satisfy the refreshControl set it up similar to this:

```
self.refreshControll = UIRefreshControl()
self.scrollView.addSubview(refreshControll)
refreshControll.addTarget(self, action: #selector(WeatherController.updateWeather), for: UIControlEvents.allEvents)
```

All we do here is create a new refreshControl, add it as a subview to the scrollView and add the target for the refreshControl. As previously said the target of the refreshControl should be a function that handles the updating of your tableViews

Greetings -Jorge