# How to get callback from button placed inside TableHeader to UiViewController (In Xamarin.iOS)

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am having button placed inside TableHeader on its click , I want to send callback to my UIViewController.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve it using mainly C# or otherwise Swift. I am writing code in C#

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's special about TableHeader?

```
public Action<object, EventArgs> VCAction;

btn.TouchUpInside += (s, e) =>
        {
            //VCAction.Invoke(s, e);
        };
```

or

```
btn.TouchUpInside += Btn_TouchUpInside;

void Btn_TouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         //VCAction.Invoke(s, e);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your  [delegate method `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)` where you return your header](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614901-tableview) cell, add this:

```
  [button addTarget:self action:@selector(yourActionMethod:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

or [Swift 3 Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617873/how-to-use-addtarget-method-in-swift-3)

```
button.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister()), for: .touchUpInside).
```

Answer (score -1):

The `target:` of the `UIButton` should be set as the `UIViewController` & `selector:` as the function responsible for handling the tap gesture.