# About sender.tag buttons

Tags: ios, swift

I have a problem with `CellViewConnection`. I have two storyboards:

- The first storyboard one is `CellViewConnection` with buttons and with PDF filesList item,
- The second one is for reading PDF files.

But I have a problem. I made the code when I pressed the first button to show me the first PDF file with the `sender.tag`. But I did not get the result of the first button and the second button I get the same as the first PDF.

How can I make the first button to get the first and the second one gets the second PDF file? 
Here is my code:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
class FirstARViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    var imagescv = ["ar1","ar2" ]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
    }




    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return imagescv.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! cellimagesar

        cell.layer.cornerRadius = 5

        cell.layer.borderWidth = 1

        cell.myImages.image = UIImage(named: imagescv [indexPath.row])
        cell.myImages.contentMode = .scaleToFill


        cell.buttonMove.tag = indexPath.item
        cell.buttonMove.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)

        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 171, height: 250)
    }
    let me = PDFViewController()
    @objc func buttonClicked(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if (sender.tag == 0) {
            PDFimport()
            let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AR1", withExtension: "pdf")

            let vc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url!)
            pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
            view.addSubview(pdfView)
            vc.delegate = (PDFViewController() as UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate)
                  }

       else if (sender.tag == 1) {
            PDFimport()
            let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)

            let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AR2", withExtension: "pdf")

            let vc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url!)
            pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
            view.addSubview(pdfView)
            vc.delegate = (PDFViewController() as UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate)
        }

    }

    func PDFimport()
    {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDF") 
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }
    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {

        return self
    }

}
```

Second View:

```
import UIKit
import PDFKit
import QuickLook

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
@available(iOS 11.0, *)

class PDFViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var document: UIDocumentInteractionController = {
        let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "", withExtension: "pdf")

        let vc = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url!)
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: url!)
        view.addSubview(pdfView)
        vc.delegate = (PDFViewController() as UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate)

        return vc

    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


       document.presentPreview(animated: true)



    }





    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }




    @IBOutlet weak var pdfView: PDFView!



    @IBAction func doAction1(_ sender: AnyObject) {

       document.presentOpenInMenu(from: view.bounds, in: view, animated: true)
    }




    @IBAction func save(_ sender: Any)
    {
       document.presentOptionsMenu(from: view.bounds, in: view, animated: true)


    }



    @IBAction func backbutton(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)

        let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "back")
        self.present(nextViewController, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }



}

@available(iOS 11.0, *)
extension PDFViewController: UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {


    func documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) -> UIViewController {
        return self
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I had used same code as you are using

My CollectionView cellForItemAt

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
        //Declaring cell 
        let cell =     collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier:              cellReuseIdentifier,for: indexPath) as! CustomCollectionViewCell

        //Adding Button reference No need to give Tags Differently 
        cell.StarImageButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(HomeVC.FavouriteButtonHandler(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

        //Return cell
        return cell
    }
```

My button Handler Required

```
@objc func FavouriteButtonHandler (sender: UIButton)
    {
        //Lets get the button position as CGPoint
        let buttonPosition : CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.HotDealsCollectionView)

        //using CGPoint we can get index Path of cell in which button was clicked
        let indexPath : IndexPath = self.HotDealsCollectionView.indexPathForItem(at: buttonPosition)!

        //Now, Do any required operation as here I need to reload my collectionView cell 
        self.HotDealsCollectionView.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])

        //You can use the index path to iterate in array of pdf files like 
        **pdfArray[indexPath.row]** //And open it

        //as per in your case
       switch indexPath.row {
       case 0:
           //Required Code for opening Pdf at index 0
           break
        case 1:
           //Required Code for opening Pdf at index 1
           break
        default:
           print("No index FOund")
        } 
    }
```

Here I actually mean instead of using button Tags why Not to directly use selected index as we usually do in cellForItemAt

Comment: did you see my code here `let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AR1", withExtension: "pdf")` only this file is worked

Comment: your issue is in opening file i.e control is getting on tag 1 but file returned is always "AR1" or in button tags ? you wrote "How can I make the first button to get the first and the second one gets the second PDF file? " This actually means issue is with button tags that even if you select second button  tag returned is always same , Did you tried checking button tag what you getting when you click on buttons Tag returned is same or different everytime

Comment: i got the same everytime , but i only got this code` let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "AR1", withExtension: "pdf")` in class `PDFViewController` and the buttons is in another class

Comment: ok bro your code is worked with me thank you , but i have a problem the PDF FILE is opened on the same View how can i change the view to another view `PDFViewController`

Comment: Why do you need anotherView to open Pdf file i.e you are doing code reusability with Opening two pdf on same view , is it do you mean PDF is nit refreshed when you open second pdf ? after opening First PDF , Sorry , I didn't got what problem you facing

Comment: I apologize for not understanding my problem
I want to open the PDF file on another page I do not want on the same page
Because when I open it on the same page I get a problem with the `TableMenu`
  If I can open the PDF file on another page, can you help me with the code?

Comment: You can try out one thing Create a new Controller Import your "PDFKit" there Suppose Name as "pdfViewVC" Now Create A String object in "pdfViewVC" and when you Select an button suppose if select button at index 0 send parameter 0 to "pdfViewVC" and there You can use Switch statement in willAppear if parameter is 0 open AR1 else AR2, Hope you getting my point , use navigationController or present "pdfViewVC"

Comment: i already have a class with PDFkit but the question is , how can i import button to pdf class ? i think i don't understand you

Comment: you do not need to take your button code to other class just you can pass a Int value to second class i.e Suppose you clicked on button 1 now Update Value of Int in second class "pdf Class" that button one was selected and execute code, So instead of Presenting pdf View in same class Just present a new Controller using navigation and in New controller set frame as "let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)". So, You need a new controller which will be only used to show pdf file opened

Comment: i am not good at swift but you mean i put in button code like this  `switch indexPath.row {
        case 0:
            if (sender.tag == 0) {
                let pdfView = PDFView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
            }
            break`

Comment: check this out if I am correctly getting what your problem is https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bgfwc6-S1vbA4dbZOy2yxUaMqHuoZqXJ

Comment: i saw your code but i got error here `let VcToPresent = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "PDFViewController") as! PDFViewController` Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

Comment: `Could not cast value of type 'UINavigationController' (0x1048cded8)`

Comment: Can you share your CodeFile if possible ? I need to look its better if you provide me instead me to create a full new project . one question , the Code output I shared from Drive is it someHow Exactly output you looking for ?

Answer (score 0):

I got Your problem ...

```
cell.buttonMove.tag = indexPath.item
cell.buttonMove.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Now If you analyze code, you can see that you are calling function with no parameter, which means UIButton never assigns to your function's parameter, which eventually lead to the issue, your tag will always be zero by default that's why it always opens your first pdf file.

Please change your code something like this

```
cell.buttonMove.tag = indexPath.item
cell.buttonMove.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.buttonClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

For more detail please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617873/how-to-use-addtarget-method-in-swift-3)

Comment: where i put this code ? i use  `if (sender.tag == 0)`