# Swift - Making a Button for UITableViewCell with .addTarget

Tags: swift, uitableview, selector

I'm trying to make two different buttons for each cell that I create in my table view. One of the buttons is a + button that will increment a label. In my testing however I cannot get the function to work. My current error says

```
Argument of #selector does not refer to an '@objc' method, property, or initializer
```

I feel like I'm implementing the .addTarget method completely wrong but I am new. Here is my code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let item = items[indexPath.section]

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell") as! AddItemCell

    cell.setCell(item: item)

    let itemAmount = cell.itemAmount as UILabel?

    cell.addButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addItem(sender:cell.addButton,forLabel:itemAmount!)), for: .touchUpInside)

}


@objc func addItem(sender: UIButton, forLabel label:UILabel) {

    print("Add Button Clicked")

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to use addTarget method in swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39617873/how-to-use-addtarget-method-in-swift-3)

Comment: Also note the click is only against the button. It's NOT on the button & label *together*. So your `addItem` method doesn't need to know of the label. You can remove that from the method

Answer (score 1):

You are using selector syntax incorrectly:

```
action: #selector(addItem(sender:cell.addButton,forLabel:itemAmount!))
```

Just say:

```
action: #selector(addItem)
```

Then, however, you will face a new problem. You think that somehow you can cause this button to call something called `addItem(sender:forLabel:)`. You can't. Change the declaration of `addItem` to `addItem(_ sender:UIButton)`. That is the only kind of function a button tap can call.

You will thus have the sender (the button), but you must figure out *from there* what the label is. (And this should be easy, because, knowing the button, you know the cell, and knowing the cell, you know the label.) You cannot pass the label as a parameter in response to the button tap — but you don't need to.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Removing those did make sense but I could not figure out how I would pass my label else-wise. What would the recommended way to pass the label be?

Comment: You know the button, so you can easily figure out what _cell_ this is, so the label is presumably that cell's `itemAmount`, right? So I don't see what the difficulty is.

Comment: You could even make this a UIButton subclass that has, itself, a `label` property that you point right at the label! There are lots of ways to do this.

Comment: The relationship is to increment the value of the label when the button is clicked. For example when the button is clicked, the label goes from "0" to "1" and so on. I am able to do this if I put the function inside my TableViewCell class. However there is an outside label on the header of my TableViewController that I also want to increment but I am not able to pass that one from outside the TableViewCell (or at least cannot figure out how to)

Comment: Fine but, as I say, you would need to ask a new question about that; it is not a suitable topic for the comments on _this_ question. This question is over (I believe). Your code will now compile and the button action method will be called. The End.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create callback function in you cell

```
class AddItemCell: UITableViewCell {

    var buttonClickCallback:(() -> Void)?

    @IBAction func onButtonClick(_ sender:Any) {
        buttonClickCallback?()
    }
}
```

and assign `buttonClickCallback` in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let item = items[indexPath.section]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "itemCell") as! AddItemCell
    cell.setCell(item: item)
    let itemAmount = cell.itemAmount as UILabel?
    cell.buttonClickCallback = {
        self.addItem(sender:cell.addButton,forLabel:itemAmount!)
    } 
}
```